# show that $M \mapsto \max( \{ \operatorname{Tr}(OM) \mid O \in O_n ( \mathbb R )\})$ with is continuous

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, trace, orthogonal-matrices

> \begin{align}
> f : M_n (\mathbb R) & \to \mathbb R \\
> M & \mapsto \max(\{\operatorname{Tr}(OM) \mid O \in O_n ( \mathbb R )\})
> \end{align}
>
> prove that $f$ is well defined and continuous

Let $M\in  M_n (\mathbb R)$

\begin{align}
h : O_n ( \mathbb R )& \to \mathbb R \\
M & \mapsto \operatorname{Tr}(OM)  \\
\end{align}

$h$ is continuous (continuity of matrix multiplication and of Trace) and $O_n ( \mathbb R )$ is a compact space so $\max(\{\operatorname{Tr}(OM) \mid O \in O_n ( \mathbb R )\})$ is well defined ie $f$ is well defined.

To prove that $f$ is continuous, I tried to show that $f$ is linear but $f$ isn't linear, and I am stuck.

Comment: You have $\operatorname{Tr}(OM)/O,$ where $O$ is an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix and $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. What does this division mean? A scalar divided by a matrix? $\qquad$

Comment: Tr(OM) where O is an n*n orthogonal matrix

Comment: That is presumably what was meant by $\operatorname{Tr}(OM),$ but what I was asking about was the _quotient_ $\operatorname{Tr}(OM)/O. \qquad$

Comment: It is not a quotient, I used the symbol "/" instead of the symbol "$\vert$"

Comment: You can write $ \max(\{\operatorname{Tr}(OM) \mid O \in O_n ( \mathbb R )\}) $ or $ \max(\{\operatorname{Tr}(OM) : O \in O_n ( \mathbb R )\}) . \qquad $

Comment: Hint: Fix $M \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\bar{M}^{\epsilon}$ be the set of all matricies $N$ such that $\|M-N\| \leq \epsilon$. This set is compact. Therefore $O_n(\mathbb{R}) \times \bar{M}^{\epsilon}$ is compact, and therefore $Tr(OM)$ attains a maximum on $O_n(\mathbb{R}) \times \bar{M}^{\epsilon}$...

Comment: @John_Krampf : Standard usage is $\|M-N\|$ instead of $||M-N||.$ The difference becomes even more conspicuous when you contrast $\|a\|\|b\|$ (coded as `\|a\|\|b\|`) with $||a|| ||b||$ (coded as `||a|| ||b||`). $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks

Comment: note that this is implicitly using the polar decomposition, and giving the sum of singular values....

Answer (score 1):

$$(A|B):=trace(A^TB)$$

is a dot product (see [here](https://sharmaeklavya2.github.io/theoremdep/nodes/linear-algebra/matrices/inner-product-space.html)) on the space of $n \times n$ matrices.

Here it doesn't matter that the $^T$ operator is absent because the transpose of an orthogonal matrix is also an orthogonal matrix.

Therefore, you just have to invoke the continuity of dot product.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are implicitly using this result : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410947/continuity-of-function-given-as-a-maximum (and the fact that inversion is continuous on the set of orthogonal matrices)

Comment: @Evariste Good reference!